# SQL Server query that both returns items with a foreign key and items that doesn't have it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a discount page where I can add Products that should have a discounted price.

Each product shows up with a number of Product Variants underneath it which can then be unchecked if they shouldn't be part of the discount.

When I press save each "CHECKED" ProductId and VariantId will be stored in a table called StoreDiscountRuleVariant.

If an existing discount page is opened in order to edit then my SQL query is no longer fetching the unchecked product-Variants from the ProductVariant table only the "checked" ones that were saved.

I want the SQL query to both return the ProductVariants that has a matching variantId foreign key in the `StoreDiscountRuleVariant` table as well as the ones that doesn't. I would also be needing an extra returned column that shows if the variantId was actually present in the `StoreDiscountRuleVariant` table - for instance isChecked=true/false.

I think this solution would be better than storing both the checked as well as the unchecked variantIds in the `StoreDiscountRuleVariant` table after saving since new ProductVariants that were added after this discount was made wouldn't show up while editing.

I was pointed in the direction of doing this:

```
 SELECT p.productid, pv.variantnameSE, pv.sku, pv.variantId, 
 rv.discountrulevariantid, rv.productvariantid FROM 
 dbo.StoreDiscountRuleVariant rv INNER JOIN dbo.Product p ON p.productId = 
 rv.productid LEFT JOIN dbo.productVariant pv ON pv.foreignProductId = 
 p.productId WHERE rv.discountruleid = 24
```

Here is the result:

Row1:

productid: 1326, variantnamese: Vit, sku: FOD46-1, variant.variantid: 822, discountrulevariantid: 572, discountrulevariant.productvariantid: 1035

ROW2:

productid: 1326, variantnamese: Svart, sku: FOD46-2, variant.variantid: 1035 , discountrulevariantid: 572, discountrulevariant.productvariantid: 1035

Only ROW2/variantid: 1035 exists in StoreDiscountRuleVariant table.
So the strange thing for me at least is that discountrulevariantid points to 1035 on both of the rows. shouldn't ROW1's discountrulevariantid: value be empty since variantid:822 doesn't exist in StoreDiscountRuleVariant.

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`.  It is unclear whether you want all *products* or all *storediscountrulevariants*.

Whichever you want, that should be the first table.  Based on the `WHERE` clause, I am assuming it the variants:

```
SELECT rv.productid, rv.productvariantid as variantid, 
       p.productnameSE as productname, pv.variantnameSE as variantname, 
       pv.sku, pv.ishidden, pp.picUrl, pp.picid 
FROM dbo.StoreDiscountRuleVariant rv LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Product p 
     ON p.productId = rv.productid LEFT JOIN
     dbo.productVariant pv
     ON pv.variantId = rv.productvariantid OUTER APPLY 
     (SELECT TOP (1) pp.* 
      FROM productpic pp 
      WHERE pp.productid = p.productid
      ORDER BY pp.isfrontpic DESC
     ) pp 
WHERE rv.discountruleid = 16 
ORDER BY rv.productid, pv.sortOrder;
```

`OUTER APPLY` is then correct for the lateral join.  `CORSS APPLY` -- like `INNER JOIN` -- would remove the unmatched variants.